# Search function issues with an array of objects vs an object of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a database I want to search from, but when making a newer, bigger database, the format changed. I would like to reformat the new format to the old, but have no idea how. Here's my situation.

I had this array of objects:

```
let people = [{"name": "John", "country": "England", "hair": "brown"},
              {"name": "Jenny", "country": "Scotland", "hair": "black"}]
```

The new array looks like this:

```
let newPeople = [{
                  "John": {"country": "England", "hair": "brown"},
                  "Jenny": {"country": "Scotland", "hair": "black"}
                }]
```

I had a search function for the `people` array that worked like this:

```
function getCountry(name) {
    for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        if (name === people[i].name) {
            return people[i].country;
        }
    }
}
```

Where this worked perfectly:

```
getCountry("Jenny") // returns "Scotland"
```

Now, in the "newPeople" array, to get Jenny's country, I have to write:

```
newPeople[0].Jenny["country"]
```

Which is incredibly convoluted, especially since every person is a part of newPeople[0] instead of the number going up by 1 per person. And I'm sure there's a method I may be missing, but I can't use the same for-loop, nor match the searched term by "name", because the object(s) don't have the "name" attribute from the old "people" array anymore.

Is there anyway I can simply convert the new array to one with the old format? If so, I will do this to the whole database rather than use the new format.

Comment: why do you have an array for `newPeople`? is it given?

Comment: This should convert the `newPeople` to old array format `Object.keys(newPeople[0]).map(k => ({name : k, ...newPeople[0][k]}));`

Comment: @NinaScholz The `newPeople` array is the "new" version of the `people` array!

Comment: @HassanImam Thank you so much!! That worked absolutely perfectly. I didn't know how to use the Object.key nor .map functions! I'd never have thought my first experience at StackOverflow would be so helpful so quickly. I will use this, and make sure to research into every part used so I can implement it later by myself if needed again. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate, you can use `Object.keys(newPeople)`. It returns an array with the keys for "newPeople". In this case, the array would be ["John", "Jenny"].

But to achieve your goal you can (if the response is always an array with just one object, like the one you posted) just:

```
function getCountry(name) {
  return newPeople[0][name].country;
}
```

If your array doesn't always contain all the names in a single object, you would have to iterate as you did before:

```
function getCountry(name) {
    for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        if (name in people[i]) {
            return people[i][name].country;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see! I now learned that `newPeople[0][name]` after declaring `name` to `"Jenny"` etc. would return that object! Thank you.
And @HassanImam showed me a quick reformat function to change it from an object of objects to the more familiar (for me) array of objects.
This has been very helpful.